# Data source reference is not valid when open downloaded file derectly from IE

Tags: java, excel, internet-explorer, mime-types

I have server. There is feature - downloading excel(XLS) file. I build report with Jasper and send binary data to the responce stream. I set ContentType as "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=windows-1252", so browser are able to recognise type of the file and offer user to open file directly or save as file to the local disk.

If user open file directly from IE(able to reproduce only in IE) he cannot create pivot table. "Data source reference is not valid" error appears:

[image: Data source reference is not valid]

I gather log with [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and algorithm of file coping is next:

1. IE download file to IE temporary storage with name as in HTTP header. For example *exportToExclel_2012.xls*
2. IE run Excel process with -Embedding attribute.
3. Excel opens with *exportToExclel_2012.xls* title.
4. Excel copy file to own temporary storage with generated name. For example *30A27D77.xls*.
5. Close IE temporary file(*exportToExclel_2012.xls*).
6. Make some file operations with Excel temporary file(seems parsing xls format). And close Excel temporary file *30A27D77.xls*.

So it seems exist some reference from 30A27D77.xls file to exportToExclel_2012.xls(cause we *exportToExclel_2012.xls* title in Excel).

Question: could you please advice me next research steps or give some evidence that server side doesn't affect Pivot Table behavior?

Comment: Mosly questions covered in this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211912.